# What is the biochemical reason for mental fatigue?

Tags: biochemistry, neuroscience, cell-biology

Is it known exactly why the brain needs sleep? What's dropping low / going high when we experience mental fatigue? I can see why low glucose could result in mental fatigue, are other reasons known?

Comment: Because the brain cell highly sensitive to glucose when its level decrease the we feel fatigue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the biochemistry, but the brain regions involved are described in this article about an fMRI study: http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2012/12/121210101630.htm

EDIT:

From what I can tell, mental fatigue is attributed to low oxygenation levels.  Here's a study that examines the effect of creatine in preventing mental fatigue: http://jtoomim.org/brain-training/watanabe2001-creatine-reduces-mentalfatigue.pdf

Comment: I know that these pieces of information don't directly answer your question, but they're related (and the best I could find).